# What is the name of the bibfile when an extension is given in \bibliography?

Tags: bibtex, latexmk

When using `bibtex`, one supplies a command like `\bibliography{test}` in the document to indicate the use of a bibfile `test.bib`, and the extension is omitted.  However, it is natural for a user also to supply an extension, as in `\bibliography{test.bib}`.  In this case, there is a difference between the actual behavior of `bibtex` and the contents of its log file and the screen output:

1. If `\bibliography{test.bib}` is in the document, then `bibtex` opens and reads `test.bib`, which is natural from the user's point of view.  However `bibtex` reports that it opens the file `test.bib.bib`:

   ```
   Database file #1: test.bib.bib
   ```
2. If the file `test.bib` does NOT exist, but the file `test.bib.bib` does exist, then  bibtex fails and, even though the file exists, it gives the following error message:

   ```
   I couldn't open database file test.bib.bib
   ```
3. If a non-bib extension is appended, as in `\bibliography{test.tbb}`, then `bibtex` uses `test.tbb.bib`.

(The tests were done on with a current TeXLive 2012 installation.)

It appears that the main logic of `bibtex` and its messages work as if the extension `.bib` is always added to the user supplied filename.  But the file opening routine silently opens a file with extension `.bib` instead of .bib.bib whenever the double `.bib` extension is present.

Is this documented behavior?  Is this behavior specific to the TeXLive 2012 implementation of bibtex, or is it the same in all versions of `bibtex`?

*Why does the answer matter?*  I am the maintainer of `latexmk`, which automatically determines dependencies from information in the `.log` and `.aux` files.  `latexmk` needs to work out the name of the `.bib` file used by `bibtex`, and also analyzes error messages from `bibtex`.  If there is version dependence in the bug/feature described above, and if `bibtex` puts incorrect information in its log file (`.blg`), it is tricky for `latexmk` to determine what to do.

Comment: I believe that the safest method is for `latexmk` to issue a warning (or an error) if the argument to `\bibfile` in the `.aux` file appears to have an extension.

Comment: MiKTeX does not exhibit the same behaviour (at least on my system), and only looks for the file after appending `.bib` (so looking for `.bib.bib` if `.bib` is already present). The behaviour of TeXLive's `bibtex` to display a different filename to the one it actually opened is clearly a bug rather than documented behaviour. It would be better to fix this bug at the TeXLive end, and `latexmk` could still warn about the incorrect extension as it is not correct and is non-portable.

Answer (score 4):

MiKTeX does not exhibit the same behaviour (at least on my system), and only looks for the file after appending `.bib` (so looking for `.bib.bib` if `.bib` is already present). The behaviour of TeXLive's `bibtex` to display a different filename to the one it actually opened is clearly a bug rather than documented behaviour. It would be better to fix this bug at the TeXLive end, and `latexmk` could still warn about the incorrect extension as it is not correct and is non-portable.